# Have a question about a particular use of inversion in English

Tags: grammar, sentence, subject-verb-inversion

> It is found that the complainant, deterred by fear of the pollution which he would have suffered had he passed near the Pariahs, did not conduct the procession.

In the above sentence, why is the inversion "had he" used here? Could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: The inversion is used as an alternative to using *if*. The clause means *which he would have suffered **if** he had passed near the Pariahs*

Comment: Yes, in certain conditions, the protasis of a conditional adjunct can take the form of a content clause with subject-auxiliary inversion. Some consider it more formal than the usual _if_ PP constuction.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion:

> ...*had he* passed near...

Is a more formal way to say:

> ...*if he had* passed near...

Comment: It's not more formal. It's merely an alternate way, like "were he to have" and "should he have" are also alternate ways.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I think many people think it *sounds* more formal, as it tends to be used in legal documents, but not much in casual speech.

Comment: *Sounding* more formal isn't more formal, of course, but I don't think people think it sounds more formal at all. People use that construction all the time in day-to-day speech (e.g., "Had I known, I'd've..."). As for it tending to be used in legal documents, do you have any basis for that assertion? I ask because I saw no such tendency during my four years working in a law office.